# Помогите разобраться с JSON

Tags: java, json

С JSON особо не знаком, но  хочу попробовать решить задачу с помощью него. 
Такая проблема, есть URL на данные, данные выглядят примерно так:

> {"Victor":["Moscov","Omsk"],"Sasha":
>   ["Tomsk"],"Oleg":["Harkov",
>   "Poltava"],"Olya":[""]}

Для соединения использую метод:

```
public static URL createUrl(String link) {
        try {
            return new URL(link);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Вопрос, как мне считать данные с файла, что бы я смогу отделить где имя, а где страны? Или где мне можно посмотреть подробно.

И можем ли мы в "StringBuilder" занести всю информацию? Просто есть вариант сплитануть по ":", потом с чётных элементов убрать все символы. И получим имя, и также сделать со странами. Но мне кажется не самый лучший вариант)

Пробовал разобраться с таким примером "https://javadevblog.com/primer-raboty-s-json-simple-v-java-parsing-i-sozdanie-json.html". Но не особо понял как мы все сделали.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь готовым решением `GSON`, https://github.com/google/gson/tree/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос, но вы скинули ссылку на вопрос. Хотел бы спросить есть строка, и он с неё достает значения которые относятся к "first_name", "last_name". А если у меня нету названия полей, как я выше написал, что мне в таком случае возвращать? и Как? 


String last_name = user.getString("last_name");